# JavaScript Regex to check for certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking for a JavaScript function that checks for the following characters (without commas) in a string. If they are present, it would return false, else returns true.

```
<,>,(,),#,"",',:,::
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function (str) { 
   return ! (/[<>()#':]|""/.test(str));
}
```

any set of  single characters can put put inside a [set of brackets]. For longer patterns, use the pipe.

edit: as patrick pointed out, if you're checking for `:` you don't need to check for `::` separately.

Comment: @patrick Funny, I gave @nickf +1 because his *didn't* negate!

Comment: @Josh - I didn't catch this at first, but the request was specifically to return `false` if the character was found.

Comment: Although, it is a bit redundant to check for both `:` and `::` since you can't have the second without the first.